# Can I turn off case sensitivity for Azure AD RedirectURI

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a Redirect URI configured like this:

```
https://<url>/RALauncher/signin-oidc
```

But if I go here:

```
https://<url>/ralauncher
```

and sign in, I get this error message:

> Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
>
> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application:
>   '<guid>'. More details: Reply address
>   did not match because of case sensitivity.

Is it possible to configure this so that the Redirect URI is not case sensitive? I can't find a setting for this in the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no setting to turn on or off the case sensitivity, i.e. it will always be case sensitive.

Generally I haven't seen it to be an issue, because app developer controls the code and you can set the configuration in Azure AD App registration appropriately.

Anyway, I don't the exact reason you have different variations on cases, but here is one approach that I can suggest that could solve your issue -

It's a collection, so you can add multiple values. So feel free to add the valid variations from your side. For example:

```
"replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://myredirecturi1",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://MyRedirectUri1",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ]
```

You can do this by editing the `Manifest` for your Azure AD app registration

[image]

or directly using Portal UI.

[image]

Comment: I set up the virtual directory with the capitalized name, and also set up the Redirect URI to match. But then some testers typed in the URL in all lowercase, and that's when I discovered this issue. I could simply make it lowercase, but users are unpredictable and I would rather have it be case insensitive as URLs typically are. But your answer is a decent workaround, because there are only a few variations that I could envision realistically being typed in.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to set up another domain that will redirect the user to the azure dependent site.

so...
[www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com) redirects to https:///ralauncher

this way site1 can be any case needed, but you can ensure that the azure dependent site has the appropriate case.